# Abbreviation Reference for NLTK Parts of Speech

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm using nltk to find the parts of speech for each word in a sentence.  It returns abbreviations that I both can't fully intuit and can't find good documentation for.

Running:

```
import nltk
sample = "There is no spoon."
tokenized_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sample)
tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_words)
print tagged_words
```

Returns:

```
[('There', 'EX'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('no', 'DT'), ('spoon', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

In the above example, I'm looking for what `DT`, `EX`, and the rest mean.

The best I have so far is to search for mentions of the abbreviations of concern in [Natural Language Processing with Python](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html), but there has to be something better.  I did also find a few literature-based resources, but I don't know how to tell which nltk is using.

Comment: Penn treebank: https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

Comment: yes!  thanks.  Any chance you could put that in an answer so I can mark it right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all possible pos tags of NLTK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk)

Comment: re. duplicate:  While the function given in the other answer does give the information I need, I didn't now it would since it only mentions listing the abbreviations and not defining them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [link](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) that you have already mentioned has two different tagsets.

> For tagset documentation, see `nltk.help.upenn_tagset()` and `nltk.help.brown_tagset()`.

In this particular example, these tags are from [Penn Treebank tagset](http://ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html).

You can also read about these tags by:

```
nltk.help.upenn_tagset('DT')
nltk.help.upenn_tagset('EX')
```

Comment: and as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15389667/1224255, the default tagset can be found with `nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER`