# What is the available TAGSET pattern for NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I know that you can get the set of word with its tag (e.g. for brown text) by using this:

`brown.tagged_set()`

And you can also change the pattern of the tagset like this:

`brown.tagged_set(tagset="universal")`

What is the available tag pattern that I can use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all possible pos tags of NLTK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk)

Comment: I think it's worth noting that NLTK as a package does not have 'a tagset' per se, but its corpora and taggers do. One reason for this is that different languages might need different tagsets. It's best to think of tagsets as the properties of specific corpora, or of the tagger used to tag those corpora, rather than as a general property of NLTK.