# Calculating loss in transformer with batch input

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-function

I am trying to build a transformer to train on the [Penn Treebank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging#Tag_sets) using PyTorch, but I am running into issues when attempting to calculate the loss of a given forward pass. For some quick context, I'm using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` and my input batches are of shape `batch_size x longest_seq_in_batch`, since I pad out all shorter sequences with 0's, so the matrix dimensions will line up. Here is my training loop:

```
# Training loop
model.train()  # Set the model to training mode
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for batch in dataloader:
        inputs = batch.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # Flatten to tensors for each element of the vocabulary
        outputs = outputs.view(-1, num_classes)

        print(f"outputs has shape {outputs.shape}\ninputs has shape {inputs.shape}")
        # Compute loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, inputs)

        # Backward pass and optimization
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()

    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloader)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs} Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")

print("Training done :)")
```

From the print statement in the above, I know `outputs` is always of shape `[32, 10007]` (where 32 is my batch size in this case). The inputs are of shape `[32, longest_seq_in_batch]` as stated above.

The problem line is `loss = criterion(outputs, inputs)`, yielding `RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported` from the compiler. I tried alleviating this by replacing the above loss calculation with a more involved one that checked each input one at a time:

```
        # Compute loss for each row individually
        loss = 0.0
        for i in range(inputs.size(0)):
            # Apply mask to exclude padding elements
            masked_inputs = inputs[i][mask[i].bool()]

            # Compute loss for the current row
            row_loss = criterion(outputs, masked_inputs.unsqueeze(0))
            loss += row_loss

        loss /= inputs.size(0)  # Average the losses across the batch
```

where `mask` is defined just before the forward pass in the training loop as `mask = (inputs != 0).float().to(device)`. But this also fails on the `row_loss` initialization line due to `ValueError: Expected input batch_size (32) to match target batch_size (1).`

I'm confused because I'm not sure what the loss function wants—how can I pass it only a one-dimensional or zero-dimensional tensor if my output dimensions are based on a batch size that is always much larger than 1?

Comment: I assume you run with a classification loss as you mentioned vocab size. However, you apply criterion(outputs, inputs) you must only pass the labels, not all inputs. Your labels shape must match with the outputs (logits) of the model (i.e. If 32 batch size, then both must be (32, vocab_size)).

Comment: [A Penn Treebank  reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk/15389667#15389667).