# How to print all the NP/VP (noun phrase, verb phrase) and sentence-structure abbreviations in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I saw [What are all possible POS tags of NLTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk) for listing the possible *POS* tags, but these don't include phrase structure grammar sentence-level tags it seems like VP (verb phrase) and NP (noun phrase), etc.. How do I print out all of those, or where are they all documented?

I'm looking at [this article](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html). It appears they are just creating grammars with arbitrary symbols, but out of convention they pick NP/etc.:

```
>>> groucho_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
... S -> NP VP
... PP -> P NP
... NP -> Det N | Det N PP | 'I'
... VP -> V NP | VP PP
... Det -> 'an' | 'my'
... N -> 'elephant' | 'pajamas'
... V -> 'shot'
... P -> 'in'
... """)


>>> sent = ['I', 'shot', 'an', 'elephant', 'in', 'my', 'pajamas']
>>> parser = nltk.ChartParser(groucho_grammar)
>>> for tree in parser.parse(sent):
...     print(tree)
...
(S
  (NP I)
  (VP
    (VP (V shot) (NP (Det an) (N elephant)))
    (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))
(S
  (NP I)
  (VP
    (V shot)
    (NP (Det an) (N elephant) (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas))))))
```

I'd like to find what all the symbols are and what they all mean (and what they allow nested inside them) if at all possible. Printing them would be a good first step though.

Comment: Found [this](https://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/List_of_symbols), and had ChatGPT list out a bunch leading to [this](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/5b0db1b4fac819b56dcc3adb227d9392). But is there no standard???